# GET Запрос + моментальный ответ

Tags: php, get

Как с помощью php реализовать такую конструкцию:
2 файла: do.php, ok.php
В файле do лежит код, который выполняется, скажем 500 секунд, при этом, я должен открывать файл ok.php, который запускает скрипт в do.php и после этого дает моментальный ответ. Это нужно для того, чтоб при последовательном запросе не ждать 500 секунд каждый запрос, а намного меньше, желательно менее 1 секунды.

Comment: Я ж надеюсь, что 500 сек. для скрипта взято с потолка? )) Если do.php подготавливает, генерирует и т.д. данные, то эти данные не плохо бы кешировать. Способ кеширования зависит от ситации: это может быть и файл, и memcached, и Local Storage на стороне клиента и т.д. К примеру, если это поиск по базе, то [Sphinx][1] это сделает за вас.

   [1]:http://sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/php [полный путь к do.php] 2>&1 &");
echo "ответ";
```